# Select rows in a table where id is equals to another id in another table and sum values in column from the result

Tags: sql, sum

I have a small situation here. I have 2 tables "facture" and "facturedet".

I can get this query working correctly:

```
SELECT * 
FROM facturedet  
WHERE facture_id IN (SELECT rowid 
                     FROM facture 
                     WHERE CAST(date_valid AS DATE) = current_date)
```

Now, in the result of the above query, I have a column "qty".

How can I sum the values in this column? I've tried

```
SELECT SUM(qty) 
FROM
    (SELECT * 
     FROM llx_facturedet 
     WHERE fk_facture IN (SELECT rowid 
                          FROM llx_facture 
                          WHERE CAST(date_valid AS DATE) = current_date))
```

Comment: Simply `SELECT SUM(qty) FROM facturedet WHERE facture_id IN (SELECT ...`?

Comment: Why can't you just do `select sum(qty) from facturedet where...`?

Comment: Although there is no need for nesting your query one level deeper, it should work. If it doesn't post sample data and expected results to clarify what you want.

Comment: And what does "no luck" actually mean? Do you get the wrong result? An Error...? A bit more detail would be useful.

Comment: I've run this in phpmyadmin `SELECT SUM(qty) FROM llx_facturedet WHERE fk_facture IN (SELECT rowid FROM llx_facture WHERE CAST(date_valid AS DATE) = current_date)` and the result is NULL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest `JOIN` and `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT SUM(fd.qty)
FROM facturedet fd JOIN
     facture f
     ON fd.facture_id = f.rowid
WHERE date_valid >= current_date AND
      date_valid < current_date INTERVAL '1 DAY';
```

Note:  This uses inequalities for the date comparison.  The exact method for adding one date varies by database.  In most databases, this structure for the comparison is better for the optimizer, which means a faster query.

Answer (score 0):

This is the final query I am using:

```
Select
    COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN f.type = 2 THEN -fd.qty ELSE fd.qty END), 0) As qty_sum
From
    ' . MAIN_DB_PREFIX . 'facturedet fd 
Inner Join
    ' . MAIN_DB_PREFIX . 'facture f On fd.fk_facture = f.rowid 
Inner Join
    ' . MAIN_DB_PREFIX . 'societe_commerciaux sc On sc.fk_soc = f.fk_soc 
Inner Join
    ' . MAIN_DB_PREFIX . 'user u On sc.fk_user = u.rowid
Where
    f.$this->typeDate Between $this->startDate And $this->endDate 
And
    u.rowid = "' . $this->userId . '"
```